# save numpy array in append mode

Tags: python, numpy, save

Is it possible to save a numpy array appending it to an already existing npy-file --- something like `np.save(filename,arr,mode='a')`?

I have several functions that have to iterate over the rows of a large array. I cannot create the array at once because of memory constrains. To avoid to create the rows over and over again, I wanted to create each row once and save it to file appending it to the previous row in the file. Later I could load the npy-file in mmap_mode, accessing the slices when needed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Edit**: this answer is somewhat outdated, see the second answer about `NpyAppendArray`. I would not recommend going for HDF5 in 2023.  But rather use numpy or zarr.

The build-in `.npy` file format is perfectly fine for working with small datasets, without relying on external modules other then `numpy`.

However, when you start having large amounts of data, the use of a file format, such as HDF5, designed to handle such datasets, is to be preferred [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16660821/1791279).

For instance, below is a solution to save `numpy` arrays in HDF5 with [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/),

*Step 1: Create an extendable [`EArray`](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/homogenous_storage.html#the-earray-class) storage*

```
import tables
import numpy as np

filename = 'outarray.h5'
ROW_SIZE = 100
NUM_COLUMNS = 200

f = tables.open_file(filename, mode='w')
atom = tables.Float64Atom()

array_c = f.create_earray(f.root, 'data', atom, (0, ROW_SIZE))

for idx in range(NUM_COLUMNS):
    x = np.random.rand(1, ROW_SIZE)
    array_c.append(x)
f.close()
```

*Step 2: Append rows to an existing dataset (if needed)*

```
f = tables.open_file(filename, mode='a')
f.root.data.append(x)
```

*Step 3: Read back a subset of the data*

```
f = tables.open_file(filename, mode='r')
print(f.root.data[1:10,2:20]) # e.g. read from disk only this part of the dataset
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me to PyTables. An a bit more simple approach using the Array class was sufficient for my purpose. I am curious why there is no append mode for `np.save`. If it would be sensible, I guess it would have been implemented.

Comment: Is this still the best method in 2018?

Comment: HDF5 being a superior file format to npy is a disputed argument. More and more papers show that HDF5 is in fact a very troubled file format and e.g. exdir is moving towards saving data in numpy files instead.

Comment: Yes, this answer is a bit outdated. Now zarr could also be a possibility for instance. Feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: Any tips on current best practices in 2022?

Comment: `.npy` is actually well suited to be appended to very efficiently. Have a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64403144/2755796

Comment: Updated the answer to indicate that it's outdated.

Answer (score 20):

I made a library to append to Numpy `.npy` files. Here an excerpt from

https://pypi.org/project/npy-append-array

## NpyAppendArray

Create Numpy `.npy` files by appending on the growth axis (0 for C order, -1
for Fortran order). It behaves like `numpy.concatenate` with the difference
that the result is stored out-of-memory in a `.npy` file and can be reused for
further appending. After creation, the file can then be read with memory
mapping (e.g. by adding `mmap_mode="r"`) which altogether allows to create and
read files (optionally) larger than the machine's main memory.

### Installation

`conda install -c conda-forge npy-append-array`

or

`pip install npy-append-array`

### Example

```py
from npy_append_array import NpyAppendArray
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
arr2 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])

filename = 'out.npy'

with NpyAppendArray(filename, delete_if_exists=True) as npaa:
    npaa.append(arr1)
    npaa.append(arr2)
    npaa.append(arr2)
    
data = np.load(filename, mmap_mode="r")

print(data)
```

### Implementation Details

NpyAppendArray contains a modified, partial version of `format.py` from the
Numpy package. It ensures that array headers are created with 21
(`=len(str(8*2**64-1))`) bytes of spare space. This allows to fit an array of
maxed out dimensions (for a 64 bit machine) without increasing the array
header size. This allows to simply rewrite the header as we append data to the
end of the `.npy` file.

Comment: Is there a way so that they stay as separate arrays rather than getting combined into one giant array?

Answer (score 12):

This is an expansion on Mohit Pandey's answer showing a full save / load example. It was tested using Python 3.6 and Numpy 1.11.3.

```
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import os

p = Path('temp.npy')
with p.open('ab') as f:
    np.save(f, np.zeros(2))
    np.save(f, np.ones(2))

with p.open('rb') as f:
    fsz = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size
    out = np.load(f)
    while f.tell() < fsz:
        out = np.vstack((out, np.load(f)))
```

> out = array([[ 0.,  0.], [ 1.,  1.]])

Comment: Thanks for this! Just one note: for a file with a lot of rows, this way of loading it is going to be too slow. Rather than using vstack (which effectively creates a new full matrix each time), it would be a lot faster to create the full matrix once, then fill in the rows.  For example: 

```size = (<num_rows>, <num_cols) # the shape of your matrix

for i in range(size[0]):
    data[i,:] = np.load(f)```

Answer (score 7):

`.npy` files contain header which has shape and dtype of the array in it. If you know what your resulting array looks like, you can write header yourself and then data in chunks. E.g., here is the code for concatenating 2d matrices:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.format as fmt

def get_header(fnames):
    dtype = None
    shape_0 = 0
    shape_1 = None
    for i, fname in enumerate(fnames):
        m = np.load(fname, mmap_mode='r') # mmap so we read only header really fast
        if i == 0:
            dtype = m.dtype
            shape_1 = m.shape[1]
        else:
            assert m.dtype == dtype
            assert m.shape[1] == shape_1
        shape_0 += m.shape[0]
    return {'descr': fmt.dtype_to_descr(dtype), 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (shape_0, shape_1)}

def concatenate(res_fname, input_fnames):
    header = get_header(input_fnames)
    with open(res_fname, 'wb') as f:
        fmt.write_array_header_2_0(f, header)
        for fname in input_fnames:
            m = np.load(fname)
            f.write(m.tostring('C'))
```

If you need a more general solution (edit header in place while appending) you'll have to resort to `fseek` tricks like in [1].

Inspired by
[1]: https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-August/044570.html (doesn't work out of the box)
[2]: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html
[3]: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/format.py

Answer (score 1):

For appending data to an already existing file using numpy.save, we should use:

```
f_handle = file(filename, 'a')
numpy.save(f_handle, arr)
f_handle.close()
```

I have checked that it works in python 2.7 and numpy 1.10.4

I have adapted the code from [here](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2007-November/030099.html), which talks about savetxt method.

Comment: I just checked and it doesn't work in `python 2.7.12` and `numpy 1.12.1`. The array just stays the same, nothing is appended. Also note that the link you provided talks about `savetxt` method, not `np.save`.

Comment: I have been able to use this type of stacking pattern successfully with python 3.5 and numpy 1.11.3. Although it was necessary to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: @PaxRomana99: This is what I am getting:
`with Path('/tmp/npy').open('wb') as f: np.save(f, np.zeros(2))`
`with Path('/tmp/npy').open('ab') as f: np.save(f, np.ones(2))`
`np.load('/tmp/npy')`                                                
`Out: array([0., 0.])`
Was hoping for `array([[0., 0.], [1., 1.]])`

Comment: @ethanabrooks: I've added an answer showing an example pattern

Comment: Should this be `open` instead of `file`?

Comment: You have to do a `np.load` for each array that you append to the file.  And make sure you leave the file open between `loads`.

Comment: I also think that it is not possible without np.load

Comment: This kind of procedures cannot work because the header is written by the first array

```
import numpy as np

fname ='/home/gg/test.npy'

arr_a = np.random.rand(5,40,10)
arr_b = np.random.rand(5,40,5)    


with open(fname, 'wb') as fh:
    np.save(fh, arr_a)

with open(fname, 'ab') as fh:
    np.save(fh, arr_b)

with open(fname, "rb") as fh:
    arr_d = np.load(fh)

print (arr_d.shape)
```
returns
```
(5, 40, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like reading the file then add new data

```
import numpy as np
import os.path

x = np.arange(10) #[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

y = np.load("save.npy") if os.path.isfile("save.npy") else [] #get data if exist
np.save("save.npy",np.append(y,x)) #save the new
```

after 2 operation:

```
print(np.load("save.npy")) #[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Comment: This is very ineffective, as you have to load the numpy file, which may not even fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The following is based upon PaxRomana99's answer.
It creates a class that you can use to save and load the arrays.
Ideally, one would also change the header of the npy file every time a new array is added in order to modify the description of the shape (see [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html) for the description of the header)

```
import numpy as np
import pickle

from pathlib import Path
import os


class npyAppendableFile():
    def __init__(self, fname, newfile=True):
        '''
        Creates a new instance of the appendable filetype
        If newfile is True, recreate the file even if already exists
        '''
        self.fname=Path(fname)
        if newfile:
            with open(self.fname, "wb") as fh:
                fh.close()
        
    def write(self, data):
        '''
        append a new array to the file
        note that this will not change the header
        '''
        with open(self.fname, "ab") as fh:
            np.save(fh, data)
            
    def load(self, axis=2):
        '''
        Load the whole file, returning all the arrays that were consecutively
        saved on top of each other
        axis defines how the arrays should be concatenated
        '''
        
        with open(self.fname, "rb") as fh:
            fsz = os.fstat(fh.fileno()).st_size
            out = np.load(fh)
            while fh.tell() < fsz:
                out = np.concatenate((out, np.load(fh)), axis=axis)
            
        return out
    
    
    def update_content(self):
        '''
        '''
        content = self.load()
        with open(self.fname, "wb") as fh:
            np.save(fh, content)

    @property
    def _dtype(self):
        return self.load().dtype

    @property
    def _actual_shape(self):
        return self.load().shape
    
    @property
    def header(self):
        '''
        Reads the header of the npy file
        '''
        with open(self.fname, "rb") as fh:
            version = np.lib.format.read_magic(fh)
            shape, fortran, dtype = np.lib.format._read_array_header(fh, version)
        
        return version, {'descr': dtype,
                         'fortran_order' : fortran,
                         'shape' : shape}
                
        
      
arr_a = np.random.rand(5,40,10)
arr_b = np.random.rand(5,40,7)    
arr_c = np.random.rand(5,40,3)    

f = npyAppendableFile("testfile.npy", True)        

f.write(arr_a)
f.write(arr_b)
f.write(arr_c)

out = f.load()

print (f.header)
print (f._actual_shape)

# after update we can load with regular np.load()
f.update_content()


new_content = np.load('testfile.npy')
print (new_content.shape)
```