# Video to numpy on disk

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, video, disk

I have a .mp4 video file that I would like to get into an numpy array and store on disk with [numpy.memmap](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html), but it is too large to read in all at once. I know how to process the file frame by frame with [scikit video](http://www.scikit-video.org), but not how to then pump that to a single numpy file on disk. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An uncompressed video is a large amount of data...[this](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5826/how-much-gb-or-tb-is-1-hour-of-raw-uncompressed-ultra-hd-film) answer gives you some idea of how much memory you'd need ("roughly 33 GB per minute for 8-bit 24 fps").

I remember attempting to do something similar when I was getting started with openCV. I'd suggest you're probably coming at your problem wrong. But if you really want to do it, you can use `numpy.save`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376581/save-numpy-array-in-append-mode) answer has some good tips on better data formats for large data sets.

Comment: hmmm hadn't thought about how much data that would be uncompressed. Thanks!